# How to develop for Arduino in VS2017?

Tags: plugins, arduino, visual-studio-2017, ide

Currently I am starting up a project with arduino.
Is there a "plug-in" for VS2017 that makes it possible to develop  in VS-2017 instead of the "normal" IDE?

Was searching for a guide that could take me there - developing arduino in vs but without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes certainly, there is Arduino IDE for Visual Studio available. You can download and use it by following the link below. It is tested with all Arduino versions from 1.0 to 1.8.x (+ 1.9 beta testing) (also supports all compatible hardware such as ESP8266, Energia IDE). The extension should be purchased after evaluating for up to 90 days. It will continue to function after the evaluation but should be purchased.
     https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualMicro.ArduinoIDEforVisualStudio

Comment: @Thank you for the graet answer .... will have a look into later 2day:-)

Comment: seem to be working :-) thanks again.

Comment: Then mark the comment as correct answer :)

Comment: Sorry of coz:-)